# Restricted user caged in a directory

Tags: ssh, sftp

We have the need to create a user that can only stay in his/her directory... no very dificult... we assined the user the /bin/rbash shell. Any try to move to another directory but his home, pointless. Good! so far so good.
Then we received the requirement to mount that directory as a network drive in windows... we found a software called SFTP Net Drive (mount via SSH) this software does its job flawlessly but when the user has assigned the /bin/rbash login shell(/etc/passwd), no connection is possible ... "connection failes due to error 103"
Normal SSh Via putty works perfectly. I even tried SCP Windows Graphical tool (Secure Copy) and again no connection is possible either. The failing protocols in both cases are SFTP.
Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with that software. and since it's a Windows software piece I think you might be stuck needing to contact their support for it

Comment: both Softwares WinSCP and  SFTP Net Drive have the the same issue. Both works perfect with user having /bin/bash shell but both don't work with users having /etc/rbash as a shell, to be honest I thing is my problem not the software.

Comment: Is there a reason you're having them use rbash instead of the usual `/bin/bash` other than for the directory isolation?  I would probably have gone the route of setting up a chroot'd folder for the user to be able to connect to, rather than forcing a user to stay in their own directory with a different shell than WinSCP and other software are used to dealing with.

Comment: rbash satisfies all the restrictions that we want to impose on the user who connects.

Comment: Seems to be a Windows setup/config problem. On what port does sftp listen? Is it the 22 default (same as ssh) port or did you reconfigured it on windows or ubuntu. Are the necessary ports open?

Comment: @LuisAngel rbash may support restrictions, but it isn't Bash by any means, and WinSCP and others tend to not function right when certain commands it looks for or uses under the hood are not supported by the remote shell, which may explain the issue you're having.  This is why I suggested that you should probably have gone down the chroot'd user directory instead of using rbash...

Comment: Since it works percfectly when user has assigned the /bin/bash loging shell and doesnt work when he has assigned /bin/rbash I dont thing is a problem of ports per se.

Comment: Just an FYI, but rbash shouldn't be used outside of a chroot'd environment according to some articles.  If you aren't running a chrooted directory then rbash is probably not what you should be using on the standard system - there's a lot of ways to work around and gain unrestricted shells...

Comment: @Thomas Ward  Do you really thing  bash and rbash are so different....
luis@vtlubuntu:~$ ls -l /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1113504 abr  4 20:30 /bin/bash
luis@vtlubuntu:~$ ls -l /bin/rbash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 may 29 15:55 /bin/rbash -> bash

rbash is kind of a simbolic link of bash problably with the -r option

Comment: I suspect it's a restriction of the OpenSSH `sftp-internal` implementation: I can confirm that WinSCP fails with message `Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running a SFTP server?` when the user's login shell is `/bin/rbash` HOWEVER changing the protocol to `SCP` in the WinSCP connection dialog works fine (and appears to respect the directory traversal restrictions of the `rbash` shell)

Comment: I can confirm, with a direct `sftp` call on an Ubuntu box to a system with a test user using `rbash` as their shell.  SFTP does not operate properly likely because it requires more permissions than rbash provides.  SCP operates differently.  If you *really* need to use SFTP, then you need to use a different approach for your directory traversal isolation and access rights restriction, because I don't think `rbash` will work proper with SFTP

Comment: @steeldriver thank you very much with scp tried and works but WinSCP not mount network drives in windows. We are trying SFTP Network Drive and Iḿ afraid only support SFTP protocol and not SCP. Nearer or the solution Thank you.

Comment: SFTP is not a need just to mount that directory in a Windows enviroment without installing cifs, nfs, etc. Just taking advantage of the SSH server

Comment: Is the string `/bin/rbash` in the file `/etc/shells`? I believe `chroot` is more easily restricted than `rbash`. Long ago, "Escaping from restricted shells" was an easy game.

Answer (score 4):

When we search for "rbash sftp doesn't work", we get a large list of messages to various forum boards that rbash and SFTP don't work.  I found a Server Fault page that might help though, so I'll borrow that content from [that post over on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/578381/rbash-to-limit-user-to-its-home-directory-closes-sftp-connection) by Server Fault user [mr.spuratic](https://serverfault.com/users/152887/mr-spuratic).  It might help explain a few things about why standard SFTP fails:

> `rbash` won't let you run commands with a leading `/`, if that's being
>   attempted then it will simply exit.
>
> Unless you're using the internal sftp-server, an attempt to exec
>   `/usr/libexec/sftp-server` will fail.
>
> Using `Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp` in the `sshd_config`
>   will fix that.
>
> However, using `rbash` won't stop sftp from wandering around your
>   filesystem, you probably want to [chroot the users
>   instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/restricting-an-ssh-scp-sftp-user-to-a-directory).

So in effect, I believe whatever's happening underneath the hood is trying to get a directory listing of a path beginning with `/`.  That will fail in `rbash`.

This said, you need to be aware that as I stated in comments and this answer I borrowed from Server Fault, `rbash` works best **when you also implement chrooted user directories**, because SFTP will *bypass* the restrictions that `rbash` puts into play and can still technically wander around your filesystem.

You really need to implement, in addition to `rbash`, chrooted user directories.  This will also protect the SFTP component from drifting around the system.

Comment: This answer is the point and makes sense I'm gonna try something else. Thank all of you guys.